# Is it possible to assign floating point values to enum in java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a requirement in which I need to create a comb box containing floating point values like JBoss 4.2.3, JBoss 6.2 etc

I tried like below

```
public enum JBossVersion {

    UNKNOWN, JBOSS 4.2.3, JBOSS 6.2
}
```

But I get error each time saying ";" ,"," ,"}" expected

Can you guys help me how to proceed this further? If there is any approach please guide me. Thanks

Comment: 4.3.2 is like no floating point I've ever seen

Comment: @Deadpool. That won't help you much because the underscores will be removed unrecoverably in the internal representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use private values in enum:

```
public enum JBossVersion {

    UNKNOWN(""),
    JBOSS_4_2_3("4.2.3"),
    JBOSS_6_2("6.2");

    private String version;

    private JBossVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

}
```

And usage `JBossVersion.JBOSS_4_2_3.getVersion()`